# Converting MatLab for loop with array code to python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, data-conversion, ar.drone

I was given code in Matlab made by someone else and asked to convert to python. However, I do not know MatLab.This is the code:

for i = 1:nWind

```
[input(a:b,:), t(a:b,1)] = EulerMethod(A(:,:,:,i),S(:,:,i),B(:,i),n,scale(:,i),tf,options);

fprintf("%d\n",i);

for j = 1:b
        vwa = generate_wind([input(j,9);input(j,10)],A(:,:,:,i),S(:,:,i),B(:,i),n,scale(:,i));
        wxa(j) = vwa(1);
        wya(j) = vwa(2);
end


% Pick random indexes for filtered inputs
rand_index = randi(tf/0.01-1,1,filter_size);
inputf(c:d,:) = input(a+rand_index,:);
wxf(c:d,1) = wxa(1,a+rand_index);
wyf(c:d,1) = wya(1,a+rand_index);
wzf(c:d,1) = 0;
```

I am confused on what [input(a:b,:), t(a:b,1)] mean and if wxf, wzf, wyf are part of the MatLab library or if it's made. Also, EulerMethod and generate_wind are seprate classes. Can someone help me convert this code to python?

The only thing I really changed so far is changing the for loop from:

for i = 1:nWind

to

for i in range(1,nWind):

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what's going on since you haven't shown us where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are initialized or if they're modified from one iteration of the loop to the next.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things to unpack here.

First, MATLAB indexing is 1-based, while Python indexing is 0-based.  So, your `for i = 1:nWind` from MATLAB should translate to `for i in range(0,nWind)` in Python (with the zero optional).  For nWind = 5, MATLAB would produce 1,2,3,4,5 while Python `range` would produce 0,1,2,3,4.

Second, `wxf`, `wyf`, and `wzf` are local variables.  MATLAB is unique in that you can assign into specific indices at the same time variables are declared.  These lines are assigning the first rows of `wxa` and `wya` (since their first index is 1) into the first columns of `wxf` and `wyf` (since their second index is 1).  MATLAB will also expand an array if you assign past its end.

Without seeing the rest of the code, I don't really know what `c` and `d` are doing.  If `c` is initialized to 1 before the loop and there's something like `c = d+1;` later, then it would be that your variables `wxf`, `wyf`, and `wzf` are being initialized on the first iteration of the loop and expanded on later iterations.  This is a common (if frowned upon) pattern in MATLAB.  If this is the case, you'd replicate it in Python by initializing to an empty array before the loop and using the array's `extend()` method inside the loop (though I bet it's frowned upon in Python, as well).  But really, we need you to edit your question to include `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` if you want to be sure this is really the case.

Third,  `EulerMethod` and `generate_wind` are functions, not classes. `EulerMethod` returns two outputs, which you'd probably replicate in Python by returning a tuple.

`[input(a:b,:), t(a:b,1)] = EulerMethod(...);` is assigning the two outputs of `EulerMethod` into specific ranges of `input` and `t`.  Similar concepts as in points 1 and 2 apply here.

Those are the answers to what you expressed confusion about.  Without sitting down and doing it myself, I don't have enough experience in Python to give more Python-specific recommendations.